# File not found: using array class in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Here is the code: error shows up for line 8 of main.hpp .

```
//main.hpp
#ifndef MAIN_HPP  // if main.hpp hasn't been included yet...
#define MAIN_HPP //   #define this so the compiler knows it has been included  

#include <array> // OFFENDING LINE 8
using std:array


class Quicksort {

public:
  void sort(array);

};

#endif
```

This header is being used by this c++ file.

```
#include "main.hpp"
// this is just the start of a quicksort algorithm, base case only
void Quicksort::sort (array list) {
  if (list.size == 1 || list.size == 0) {
    return;
  }
```

}

Why am I getting this error? I thought my C++ and g++ were fine. Any other reasons it might not be working?

I'm compiling with the command (on Mac, with newest X-Code): g++ version 4.2 
    g++ -Wall -c quicksort.cpp

When I use -std=c++11 it says:
unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"

Comment: You probably want `-std=c++11`.

Comment: GCC 4.2 is 5 years old, it doesn't support C++11. Either install a newer GCC or use Clang and libc++

Comment: Is there a way to update?

Comment: I'd honestly just get Clang if I was on a Mac.

Comment: Apple will not ship anything newer than GCC 4.2 because of licensing issues, so you need to install it yourself from e.g. homebrew

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, I have gone the route of getting Mac Ports and am working on updating it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need C++11 support to be able to include `<array>`. On GCC you would need to use the `-std=c++0x` flag (or -std=c++11 on the latest versions). 
Furthermore, `array` lives in the `std` namespace, and you *probably* mean to pass a reference:

```
void sort(std::array&);
```

If your compiler does not support the relevant parts of C++11, you can use the version from TR1:

```
#include <tr1/array>

...
std::tr1::array<int, 5> a = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` (`-std=c++0x` and `-std=gnu++0x` on older versions of GCC before 4.7.0), the latter which includes extensions. If that still doesn't work then you need a more recent version of GCC.